# cambiar de estado "activo" a "inactivo" automaticamente php

Tags: php

Necesito que el estado "activo" cambie automáticamente al estado "inactivo" cuando la fecha actual sea mayor a la fecha límite (cuando se venza).

No tengo el código conmigo pero podría ayudarme un ejemplo.

Les agradecería un montón.

Comment: cambiar el estado de que?

Comment: tomate el tiempo de leer [ask] también realiza el [tour] una vez hecho esto por favor dale editar y mejora tu pregunta pues no se entiende de que hablas

Comment: Falta demasiado contexto. Es en javascript o en php?. en cualquier caso, siempre es un un if()

Comment: `if ($vencido) cambiarEstado();`

Comment: basicamente quiero que se cambie de estado "activo" a "inactivo" cuando una condición se cumpla, en este caso vendria siendo cuando la fecha actual sea mayor a la fecha límite (cuando se venza )

Comment: Si esto es mayor que esto. Si esto es diferente de aquello. Por lo que entiendo solo es una condicionante lo que necesita "Necesito que el estado se cambie automáticamente", La única forma que conozco para detectar esto es con un condicionante o un evento.

Comment: cómo lo haría de forma automatica? sin que el usuario tenga que hacerlo manualmente

Comment: es casi imposible saberlo sin ver el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$fecha_limite = strtotime("20-11-2018 21:00:00");

$estado = true;
if($fecha_actual > $fecha_limite){
    $estado = false;
}
```

o si prefieres te puede servir esto:

```
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$fecha_limite = strtotime("20-11-2018 21:00:00");

$estado = "activo";
if($fecha_actual > $fecha_limite){
     $estado = "inactivo";
}
```

Espero te des una idea

Comment: A mi parecer no están amplia como parece. El usuario está limitando a comprar dos fechas, una actual y una limitante, si esa condición se cumple ejecutar una acción. Si estoy mal lo puedo borrar.

Comment: Entiendo, me queda claro, saludos.

Comment: estaré implementando esto, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.